# .NET Core Database First Update Only One Table

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using `.NET Core 2.1` with Database first approach.  I pulled my tables in with the command

```
Scaffold-DbContext "My_Connection_String;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DBContext -Context My_Entities -UseDatabaseNames -Tables My_Tables -force
```

However, when I re-run this command, it re-creates all the table classes and the context.  I then have to add `virtual` to all the relationships and change the namespace which is annoying.

Lets say I update a database table, how do I change my command so only the table I change is updated in the code?

Also, I want to keep with Database first and **not** switch to Code first.

Comment: I've faced this problem before, and rather than find a solution, I tried a cheeky workaround using version control (git and tfs in visual studio). I would commit every time before I re-ran the EF command. Then after running the command it would obviously mess up all the custom code I added in the classes. I would then right click each of those classes click **Undo Changes** except that one table that I wanted to keep updated. This way I got my old code back without much hassle. I understand this isn't a solution but it might save you some time meanwhile.

Comment: @Mausam ya that's what it looks like I'll have to do, just have to be careful not to undo changes for classes where the relationship was added.